# In VS 2012,How to publish a web application which has more than one class project & third party dll’s?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

In VS 2012,How to publish a web application which has more than one class project & third party dll’s?

I am working on Visual Studio 2012 using .Net Framework 4.0, targeting x64
My Web Project Solution has two class projects. One of the class project has a third party dll (Chilkat) for doing the SFTP functionality.

When I deploy the published version web application, do I need to move the third party dll to web bin folder path?

In the server, Third Party dll works fine for .exe version of windows application. But dll doesn’t work, if I move the dll to Inetpub – Web directory.

I am trying to find the solutions to resolve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

See this [page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files), you may find it useful.